# Is it possible to reflect enum's variable out by enum type in Golang

Tags: go, enums

For example, I have an enum like:

```
type Status int

const (
     Normal Status = itoa
     Blocked 
)
```

The type of `Status` is known, can I get the `"Normal" and "Blocked"` by `Status`. If there is one way, I think it will be by `reflect`.

I do not want to use mapping to solve it. Because this function is used in a library. it is kind of stateless.

Is there any other ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Constant names are not exposed in the reflect API.

Use the [stringer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) tool.